# Playing streaming video using default media player

Tags: java, video, video-streaming, media-player, flash

I have a link like `http://..../video.mp4`. The task is run a video using the installed on OS media player or flash player in full screen mode.

Please give me a link where I can read about this or maybe we have some code examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a class called `Desktop`. It should contain a method called `Desktop.open()`.

With this class you can also open a link in the systems default browser (`Desktop.browse(url);`)

```
File f = new File("/path/to/video.avi");
Desktop.open(f);
```

Comment: How i can run in full screen mode?

Comment: Not sure, but i think this won't work out of the box. A possible Workaround: let a Robot() press F11 for you, after opening the default-player. But i haven't tried that yet.